# Consequences of usage of a shared library which dlopens another shared library with different built types

Tags: c++, linux

I have a binary which links to lib1.so. lib1.so library dlopen lib2.so. But we can't guarantee that the built type of lib1.so and lib2.so are the same. For example, lib1.so might be debug built where as lib2.so might be optimized built or vice versa. 
Please advice me regarding the consequences of the above usage.

Comment: Normally this should not be a problem, as long as you don't use something like `ifdef NDEBUG ... some ABI-changing code ...#endif`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem mixing debug and optimized builds with shared libraries.